# PyQt5 - Move QTcpServer to subprocess

Tags: python, pyqt5, subprocess, qthread, qtcpserver

I am trying to run a QtcpServer on a different thread or even better on a subprocess in python using PyQt5.

Running it on a different QThread I get this error as soon as the server tries to send something to the client:

QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QNativeSocketEngine(0x295023f7c50), parent's thread is QThread(0x29501ed7e30), current thread is QThread(0x2957feaffb0)

After some googeling i found that I should not run a QTcpServer on a different thread. So I decided to run it as a separate subprocess, so it should have its own thread where everything is initialized and **should** work... at least in my own theory.. The server starts up alright, it prints out the message "listening for connections on port 2001"  but I cannot connect with my client.

Connecting to 127.0.0.1 ...
TCP connection error :10061

Any help is greatly appreciated...

here is my code:

main.py:

```
import sys import serverSub 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class UiMainWindow(QMainWindow):

    serverSp = serverSub.TcpSubprocess()
    def __init__(self):
        super(UiMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.serverSp.start_server()
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = UiMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

serverSub.py:

```
import subprocess
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class TcpSubprocess(QObject):
# Start the server as a subprocess
    p = subprocess.Popen
    def start_server(self):
        command = ['python', 'server2.py']
        self.p = subprocess.Popen(command)
```

server2.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QHostAddress, QTcpServer
    
class Server(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.TCP_LISTEN_TO_PORT = 2001
        self.server = QTcpServer()
        self.server.newConnection.connect(self.on_new_connection)
        self.start_server()
        self.socket = None

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print("server exited..")

    def on_new_connection(self):
        while self.server.hasPendingConnections():
            self.set_socket(self.server.nextPendingConnection())

    def start_server(self):
        if self.server.listen(
                QHostAddress.Any, self.TCP_LISTEN_TO_PORT
        ):
            print("Server is listening on port: {}".format(self.TCP_LISTEN_TO_PORT))
        else:
            print("Server couldn't wake up")
            
    def set_socket(self, socket):
        self.socket = socket
        self.socket.connected.connect(self.on_connected)
        self.socket.disconnected.connect(self.on_disconnected)
        self.socket.readyRead.connect(self.on_ready_read)
        print("Client connected from Ip %s" % self.socket.peerAddress().toString())

    def on_ready_read(self):
        msg = self.socket.readAll()
        msg_txt = str(msg, 'utf-8').strip()
        messages = msg_txt.split("\r")
        segments = messages[0].split(",")
        

        if segments[0] == "STA":
            status = int(segments[1])
            # send back OK message
            out = 'OK\r'
            self.socket.write(bytearray(out, 'ascii'))
            
    def on_connected(self):
        print("Client connected")


    def on_disconnected(self):
        print("Client disconnected")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Server()
```

Comment: The instance of `Server` will be garbage-collected immediately after it's created. Also, it makes no sense to run the server without an event-loop, which obviously requires a local QApplication. Thus, the reason why you get that Connection Refused error is simply because there is nothing (i.e. no running process) listening on that port. (If you add `print('die')` to the end of *server2.py* you can confirm this for yourself). I suggest you look at some of the [Qt Network Examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-network.html) to learn how to use the TCP classes correctly.

Comment: Why do you use Qt for such a thing? Python has its own server/tcp/udp etc stuff. No need to depend on Qt for that.

Comment: @buhtz I am using QT for many other things in this project, so it is convenient to use Qt also for the tcp.

Comment: The Python library is more stable and consistent in relation to Qt. I never understood why developers using Qt for something else then GUI.